# Apply :focus-visible when focusing element programatically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to apply styling to my element when I'm focus it using my keyboard or when focused programatically using `HTMLElement.focus()`.

E.g in the example below. I want the `<div>` to have blue borders initially or when I focus with tab. I only want it to have red border when I click the `<div>` using my mouse.

Is this possible?

EDIT1: Changed from triggering focus with a button to just on render as this scenario wasn't accurate to my actual issue.

EDIT2: Changed from vanilla JS to React as I though that might be the issue. Seems like it still works like I want to to here, but not in my App :(. I have no clue why.

```js
const useFocusOnMount = (ref) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.focus();
    }
  }, [ref]);
};


const App = (props) => {
  const divRef = React.useRef(null)
  
  useFocusOnMount(divRef);

  return (
  <div ref={divRef} role="listbox" tabindex="0" className="focusable">
    <div data-testid="displayValue">Lol</div>
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.focusable {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

.focusable:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.focusable:focus-visible {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It does have a blue border when using keyboard and a red border when clicking with a mouse?

Comment: I want it to get a blue border even when clicking the button with my mouse. In my real world case i dont use a button to trigger the focus(), so maybe this was a bad example. I'll change it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you want this, and I would advise you to find an other way to do what you want (e.g, why not use only `:focus`?).
But for the hack, you can trick the browser in thinking your div is editable, it *should** make it trigger its `focus-visible` rule.

```js
const focusable = document.getElementById('focusable');
const button = document.getElementById('button');

const onClickHandler = (e) => {
  focusable.contentEditable = true;
  focusable.focus();
  focusable.contentEditable = false;
};

button.addEventListener("click", onClickHandler);
```

```css
.focusable {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

.focusable:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.focusable:focus-visible {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="focusable" class="focusable" tabIndex=0>Lol</div>
<button id="button">Focus Lol</button>
```

*I only tested in latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. It might be a React issue. I tested it in vanilla js by triggering focus on the div without clicking the button. Just on render, which is closer to my actual case and then :focus-visible worked which was strange as it doesn't in my React app.
Can't get the snippet to work though:/

Comment: Well triggering a JS focus as in your original snippet did reproduce the issue. Did you try to set the `contentEditable` in your react env?

Comment: What in the world. I changed to a react example now and it works the way wish it would in my app :S

Comment: No I havent tried the hack you showed me. As you said, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: My point is that whatever solution you'll get should be avoided. Just don't put yourself in this situation. Now, you've asked a question, which I did answer, editing said question to make existing answers invalid is not very "nice". Your question did show an issue, I answered to that. It would be nice to roll-back your edits to the first revision, and if you find out that the issue in your actual code was caused by something else (and that you still need someone's help with it), you can ask a new question (but be careful to ensure your minimal repro does reproduce the issue).

Comment: I agree. You solution is still valid though as it "solves" my issue. No I don't want to use :focus as that will style the element when click it with my mouse, which is not needed.

What I am wondering now is why it works without setting `contentEditable` here, but not in my App

Comment: But I had to edit my question as using a button to trigger the focus was not very accurate to my issue as :focus-visible use Keyboard events as a heuristic to determine if the styling should be applied.

Comment: Yes but the click was on the button, not on the div. The problem was more likely caused by calling `.focus()`. Which is probably your problem too. I'm not sure what else you have in your app, or why it works here (maybe a timing thing, maybe you first had focus somewhere else in your app etc.), but your first snippet did repro the issue, clicking the button was showing a red border.

Comment: I'll accept your answer for now, but it is very hacky idd and should be avoided. I'll try to replicate my issue in the stackoverflow snippet. Maybe that will help me figure what is different here than in my App.

Comment: It still works in Mozilla Firefox 106.0.3 but it doesn't work in Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.35.

Comment: @gouessej Funny thing, in Mozilla you can now use `.focus({focusVisible: true})`, so this hack works exactly where you can just live without it...

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev Yes but it's marked experimental in MDN, I refrain myself from using such methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: Thanks! Had the same problem with button after migrating bootstrap 4.x to bootstrap 5.3 as in 5.3 the button focus outline is styled for :focus-visible while in 4.x was styles for :focus. Now I have a fix method for this:
  private initialFocusFixForButtons(elementToFocus: HTMLElement): void {
    if (elementToFocus.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      elementToFocus.contentEditable = 'true';
      elementToFocus.focus();
      elementToFocus.contentEditable = 'false';
    } else {
      elementToFocus.focus();
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, this is a very basic request. Focus-visible gives us the power to create more prominent focus indicators for mouse-free users who most require them, while hiding them from users who don't. If you dismiss a modal with the escape key, to use a common programmatic example, you might want to see a focus ring, whereas if you clicked a close button, you might not.

Please note that in most scenarios, the CSS :focus-visible pseudo selector is quite sensitive to programmatic focus immediately following a key press. The example of dismissing a modal is one of the few that might require some custom script since multiple fetches might need to occur before the element to receive focus has rendered.

I created [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/cagerattler/pen/poQqPBq?editors=1111) to illustrate the custom script required in that scenario.

The heavy lifting is this method:

```
// our method to show programatic focus-visible
function showProgrammaticFocusVisible(container){
  let focusedViaMouseAttributeName = 'data-focused-via-mouse';
  let navigatingViaMouse = false;
  
  container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    navigatingViaMoused = true;
    // wait for next thread, after focusin event
    setTimeout(function(){
      navigatingViaMouse = false;
    })
  });
  
  container.addEventListener('focusin', function(e){
    // wait for next thread, after click event
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(navigatingViaMouse){
        e.target.dataset.focusedViaMouse = 'true';
      } else {
        e.target.dataset.focusedViaMouse = 'false';
      }
    })
    
  });
  
  container.addEventListener('focusout', function(e){
    e.target.dataset.focusedViaMouse = '';
  });
}
```

In the codepen, I chose to limit the programmatic focus-visible behavior to a specific class, but it could be implemented more broadly.

```
:focus-visible,
.show-focus-visible[focused-via-mouse=false] {
  outline: solid 2px blue;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.show-focus-visible[focused-via-mouse=true] {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfocus elements if you point to the element itself.
You must style element with an event listener on body, because `outside` click is on **body**, not on the element itself.

You can use `e` like `this` to spot where users click.

If `e` (click) !== (is different to/not on) `focs` (element) outline = 0.

```js
const focs=document.getElementById('focs');
const focsb=document.getElementById('focsb');

document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target!==focs&&e.target!==focsb) {
     focs.style="outline: 0";
  } else if (e.target==focs&&e.target!==focsb) {
     focs.style="outline: 2px solid #000";
  } else {
     focs.style="outline: 2px solid #CC0000";
  };
});
```

```html
<input id="focs" type="text">
<button id="focsb">Focus</button>
```